# install newer software by just replacing files on file system

Tags: installation, filesystems

Hypothetical question about installation of software. An .exe or .dmg file of version 1 is downloaded and installed. The folders in file system that it creates and stores it's info in it are A, B and C. Now we replace version 1 files on file system with version 2 files(it is known that it also creates A,B,C folders with different content at the same path). Did we just install version 2 successfully?

Operating system in question is OS X. Software pretty much any. Are there some Preferences files that should also be updated?

Comment: Short answer: It depends. Your question is too broad. Please be more specific.

Comment: well, the question isn't bound to one software. I updated the question with  operating system specifics.

Comment: Look at the install scripts for a few programs. That will give you some clues.

Comment: It being not specifically about a particular piece of software is the reason it's broad.  Your question even with the edit is still to broad to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer can be, "No, unless it works, then yes.".  This will vary from application to application, and with differant versions within applications.

Most applications use shared libraries and components, that are installed with the first piece of software that uses them. This has several implications:

1. Some important components of your software may not be being installed at the same time that the software in question is installed.
2. Other applications may rely on objects/components your program installs
3. Most applications must use the exact version of a dependency that the program was compiled to use.
4. When another application that uses a shared object is updated/upgraded, it may update the shared object. If no other piece of software is aware that the shared object is used by a different product, it has no reason not to remove the existing (now outdated) version of the object.

For these reasons, every major OS has implemented a scheme by which application components and version dependencies are tracked. There are several for Mac, including MacPorts, Fink, and Homebrew.

So, as you can tell, this entirely depends on:

1. the specific apps dependencies
2. The other apps you have installed and their shared dependencies
3. The package management approach you use

If the app in question has no external dependencies, and you don't ever want to use a package manager to reinstall/update/remove the program, then it will work.

if the app has external depends, but is the only app to use that depend on the system, and you don't ever want to use a package manager to reinstall/update/remove the program, then it will work.

In all other cases, no, it will not work, and may cause bizarre and unpredictable problems. in particular watch out when performing in place upgrades to a new OS version.